# Как остановить воспроизведение wav файла linphone

Tags: linux, консоль, sip, voip

Пользуюсь linphonecsh.
Проигрываю wav file делаю так

```
linphonecsh generic "play myfile.wav"
```

Воспроизводится, все отлично. **Мне нужно остановить воспроизведение, как мне это сделать?**

Comment: в зависимости от контекста могу предложить варианты: `pause`, `resume` или `play ''`

Comment: @Fat-Zer pause и resume, это сам вызов поставить на паузу или возобновить, это не то. С плеем похоже на правду. В старых версиях канает, а вот в linphone-nogtk >3.12 есть бага. Если мы воспроизводим файл, потом делаем вызов, все последующие файлы которые мы будем играть будут накладываться на тот что мог играть до вызова

Comment: если верить `help`'у у `play` два назначения: или играть файл во время удержания вызова, или проигрывать вместо вызова во время звонка... отсюда и вариации с `pause` для второго случая... а `resume` скорей всего не то, но формально тоже останавливает игру файла =)... по поводу бага можно, в качестве хака, попробовать все команды подряд... `play ''; resume; pause`, или `resume; play ''; pause`, или просто `resume; pause`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer долгими страданиями пришел к хаку - перед звонком как Вы мне посоветовали делаю play '', а вот после то что мне надо, и в момент поднятой трубки все работает хорошо. Главное не забывать про багу. Спасибо. Надеюсь что кто нибудь сюда когда нибудь выложит как решить багу...